# how to make a temporary object from withing the class function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm writing this code and there is a need to send objects as parameters in functions. My problem is one of the objects needs to be resued with its original values but as I need to return an object from the functions.

I don't know how I can send the answer and keep the original values in the object
safe for reuse. Is there any way to make an object from the class declaration itself?

```
import math

class Points(object):
 def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z


def __sub__(self, no):
    
    no.x = no.x - self.x
    no.y = no.y - self.y
    no.z = no.z - self.z
    
    return(no)

def dot(self, no):
    ans = (self.x * no.x)+(self.y * no.y)+(self.z * no.z)
    return ans

def cross(self, no):
    x = (self.y * no.z)-(self.z * no.y)
    y = (self.x * no.z)-(self.z * no.x)
    z = (self.x * no.y)-(self.y * no.x)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    return(self)
    
def absolute(self):
    return pow((self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2 + self.z ** 2), 0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
points = list()
for i in range(4):
    a = list(map(float, input().split()))
    points.append(a)

a, b, c, d = Points(*points[0]), Points(*points[1]), Points(*points[2]), Points(*points[3])
x = (b - a).cross(c - b)
y = (c - b).cross(d - c)
angle = math.acos(x.dot(y) / (x.absolute() * y.absolute()))

print("%.2f" % math.degrees(angle))
```

I want to do something like:

```
def function_name(self,other)
  temp.x = self.x + other.x
  temp.y = self.y + other.y
  return temp
```

This way both input objects will have their original values but I don't know how to get that temp.

Comment: (1) Try using periods in your question to separate sentences. It is very hard to read and understand. (2) What is `temp`? Is it an instance of `Points`? If so, just create a new object and then return it.

Comment: Are you asking how to *copy* an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone who helped. I got the answer to what I was looking. I wanted an object to act as a container that can store the class variables,
and I didn't knew I can just make a new object of the class from within it!

```
import math
class Points(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z

    def __sub__(self, no):
        return  Points((self.x-no.x),(self.y-no.y),(self.z-no.z))

    def dot(self, no):
        return (self.x*no.x)+(self.y*no.y)+(self.z*no.z)

    def cross(self, no):
        return Points((self.y*no.z-self.z*no.y),(self.z*no.x-self.x*no.z),(self.x*no.y-self.y*no.x))
        
    def absolute(self):
        return pow((self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2 + self.z ** 2), 0.5)
```

As you can see using points, i.e the constructor for class Points, I can store the result of any operations and can return it as an object while not altering my input objects.

Comment: Thanks man as English isn't my first language, My Grammar is weak!

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is reuse a variable that you have passed to a class object, you can just duplicate it in your `__init__` statement, or in the function where you use it.

e.g

```
class Foo:
  
  def __init__(self, my_var1, my_var2):
    self.my_var1 = my_var1
    self.my_var2 = my_var2

  def bar(self):
    bar_var1 = self.my_var1
    bar_var2 = self.my_var2
    bar_var1 = bar_var1 + bar_var2
    return bar_var1
```

Although, I am a little confused by why you are attempting to return `self` in your `cross` function, as `self` is a class parameter, and you don't seem to be using it in its [intended purpose.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709832/10778286) If you're confused about how you should be using `self`, a brief read through the [python class tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) might be helpful. However, barring that, I hope this answers your question.